# Implementing the min & max function with group by and having in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this below sql query which i have to implement the same using linq but i am unable to create a linq statement for the same. Please provide some help.

```sql
Declare @DateTime datetime 
set @DateTime = '06/20/2012';-- To get the yesterday/any day attendance record.
With Cte
as
(
    Select EmployeeiD,(convert(varchar,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Min(DateAndTime),Max(DateAndTime))/60)) + ':' 
      + convert(varchar,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Min(DateAndTime),Max(DateAndTime))/60)))WorkedHoursAndMinutes,
    Min(DateAndTime) As DateAndTime from EmployeeAttendance group by
    EmployeeiD,convert(varchar,DateAndTime,101),convert(varchar,DateAndTime,101) having (
    (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Min(DateAndTime),Max(DateAndTime))/60) >= 12
        or (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Min(DateAndTime),Max(DateAndTime))) = 0 )
)
select * from Cte
where convert(varchar,Cte.DateAndTime,103) = 
           (select convert(varchar,@DateTime,103));
```

Comment: The above query is about the find out the employee record worked more than 12 hours for a day or the difference between login and logout time is 0.

Answer (score 1):

As you only show *how* you tried to achieve something it's kinda hard to exactly infer *what* you want. But I think this is it:

```
employeeAttendances.Where(e => e.DateAndTime >= d1 && e.DateAndTime < d2)
.GroupBy (e => e.EmployeeiD)
.Select (g => new 
{ 
    g.Key, 
    Diff = EntityFunctions.DiffHours(g.Min(x => x.DateAndTime),
                                     g.Max(x => x.DateAndTime)) 
} )
.Where(a => a.Diff > 12 || a.Diff == 0)
```

It calculates the difference between the minimum and maximum time on one specific day for each `EmployeeID`.